Cannot change volume or access audio settings in KDE Plasma suddenly
One time when I rebooted my computer, suddenly, the audio won't change and the audio settings only say No output or input devices found. I have replaced pulseaudio with pipewire, but it stilled worked after a reboot following the replacement.
When using kmix and rebooting again, the audio can be changed, but the audio applet in KDE Plasma shows the same message. I can still hear audio, but I need to manually change it with programs like alsamixer or kmix. Also, I tried making the same conditions on Virtualbox with pipewire instead of pulseaudio, and the audio worked in the virtual machine. How can I fix plasma-pa's audio problem?
My Linux distribution is Debian Sid.
Output of pactl info:
Connection failure: Invalid server
pa_context_connect() failed: Invalid server

Version of packages:
plasma-pa: 4:5.27.10-1+b2
pipewire: 1.0.5-1+b1
pipewire-pulse: 1.0.5-1+b1


Apparently, I had PULSE_SERVER="" in my /etc/environment file. I removed that line and rebooted. Then, everything worked.
